# Not able to do swipe operation in appium. Method is getting deprecated

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to do swipe operation using swipe(direction, duration) method in appium. But swipe method is getting deprecated.And getting exception on console

```
FAILED: test
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
```

This is my code

```
MobileElement abc = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout"));
abc.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 6000);
```

I think swipe() method is not available. PFA screenshot for reference.

1)eclipse screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRTdw.png

2)Methods unavailable screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzygI.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

swipe() method from driver has been deprecated in the latest versions of Appium. Not only swipe(), even tap(), pinch(), zoom() have also been deprecated.

You would now have to use TouchActions to perform swipe operation. Sample code -

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.press(startX, startY).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

Comment: hi @anish You say in comment TouchActions to be used but you have used TouchAction. When I use TouchAction I am not able to swipe. (driver is AppiumDriver<WebElement>)

Comment: I am getting a warning for the first line as "TouchAction is a raw type. References to generic type TouchAction<T> should be parameterized", how to fix it?