# AttributeError: module 'appium.webdriver' has no attribute 'TouchActions'

Tags: python, android, selenium, gesture-recognition

I've tried to use the TouchActions from Appium to perform a horizontal banner swipe, but I received the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'appium.webdriver' has no attribute 'TouchActions'
```

Code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'com.project.ProjectName:id/bannersRecyclerView')))
# swipe right = dx: -992.0 dy: 11.0
# swipe left = dx: 992.0 dy: 11.0
action = webdriver.TouchActions(driver)
action.press(x=-992, y=11).move_to(x=0, y=-11).release().perform()
```

From the imported modules:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchAction
```

Might be similar to: [having problem in touchactions in appium using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525386/having-problem-in-touchactions-in-appium-using-python)

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS: tried
` TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.press(startX, startY).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();`
and  is not working as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887123/not-able-to-do-swipe-operation-in-appium-method-is-getting-deprecated

Comment: Tried:
`actions = TouchAction(driver)
actions.scroll_from_element(element, -992, 11)
actions.scroll(11, 992)
actions.perform()`
and got `AttributeError: 'TouchAction' object has no attribute 'scroll_from_element'`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
```

Check that your code is up to date to the latest release [Appium Python Client](https://github.com/appium/python-client)

However, you can also try a different approach, as that looks like a wrapper around W3C actions: [Actions](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#actions)

There are many ways to work around this, I would suggest you to not hard-code the coordinates, specially if you are automating a horizontal banner swipe.

Try to use the id or a similar locator of that specific banner.

**The actions way**:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id(banner_id)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click_and_hold(element)
actions.move_by_offset(xoffset,yoffset)
actions.release()
actions.perform()
```

[touch-actions.md](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md)